# Existe alguma maneira de saber se um array é associativo ou sequencial?

Tags: php, array

Em PHP, um `array` pode ser tanto associativo como ele pode ser uma lista, com números sequenciais.

Existe alguma maneira de detectar essa diferença em PHP?

Exemplo:

```
$a = array('item 1', 'dois' => 'item 2'); // Associativo

$b = array('item 1', 'item 2'); // Sequencial
```

Comment: No final vc quer o retorno por exemplo, array `x` é númerico, ou `x`é associativo ou `x` é misto. Vejo zebras hahaha :D

Comment: @rray acabei respondendo à minha pergunta também. O `array` no PHP querendo ou não é uma coisa bagunçada!

Comment: Provavelmente só olhando o fonte. Pro PHP, aparentemente sempre é associativo: http://ideone.com/iEDhkz - duvido muito que tenha alguma flag indicando a diferença internamente (e não tou muito afim de olhar o source pra isso).

Comment: Na verdade tô achando que saí mais em conta usar SplFixedArray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Considerações

Conforme [documentação oficial](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php), um *array* pode, apenas, ter chaves do tipo inteiro ou *strings*. O valor pode ser de qualquer tipo.

> A chave pode ser um inteiro ou uma string. O valor pode ser de qualquer tipo.

Algumas coerções que podem ocorrer:

1. *Strings* contendo inteiros válidos, serão convertidos para o tipo inteiro. Por exemplo, a chave `"8"` será, na verdade, armazenada como `8`. Entretanto, `"08"` não será convertido, por não ser um inteiro decimal válido.

Portanto, o *array* `["8" => "foo"]` deve ser considerado como *array* de índices numéricos e não associativo.

2. *Floats* também são convertidos para inteiros; isso significa que a parte fracionada será removida. Por exemplo, a chave `8.7` será na verdade armazenada como `8`.

Portanto, o *array* `[8.7 => "foo"]` deve ser considerado como *array* de índices numéricos também.

> *Floats* também serão convertidos para inteiros inclusive para valores negativos. A chave `-5.6` será na verdade armazenada como `-5`.

3. *Booleanos* são convertidos para inteiros, igualmente; por exemplo, a chave `true`, será na verdade armazenada como `1` e a chave `false` como `0`.

Portanto, o *array* `[true => "foo", false => "bar]` deve ser considerado como *array* de índices numéricos também.

4. *Null* será convertido para uma *string* vazia; por exemplo, a chave `null` na verdade será armazenada como `""`.

Portanto, o *array* `[null => "foo"]` deve ser considerado como *array* associativo.

Outras considerações:

- *Arrays* mistos, tal como `["foo", "key" => "bar"]` serão considerados como associativos, bem como de índices numéricos.
- Um *array* de índices numéricos não deixa de sê-lo quando seus índices não forem sequenciais; portanto o *array* `[1 => "foo", 0 => "bar"]` deve ser considerado, ainda, como de índices numéricos.
- Semelhantemente, um *array* com índices numéricos que tiver um de seus valores removidos (ou que a sequência dos índices não for natural) também continuará sendo de índices numéricos; portanto o *array* `[0 => "foo", 1 => "bar", 6 => "baz"]` deve ser considerado como de índices numéricos.

### Contextos a serem testados

> **Atenção!** Para o restante da resposta, adotou-se como padrão que um *array* dito sequencial é, na verdade, um *array* de índices numéricos, mas não necessariamente de índices sequenciais.

Dito isso, defini alguns testes que as funções devem ser submetidas:

```php
/**
 * Lista de testes que a função deve ser submetida.
 * 
 * Cada item da lista deve ser um array com três índices.
 * O primeiro, "array", com o array a ser testado pela função.
 * O segundo, "is_sequential", um valor booleano esperado como retorno da função is_sequential.
 * O terceiro, "is_associative", um valor booleano esperado como retorno da função is_associative.
 */

$tests = array();

// Teste 1: Array com índices numéricos sequenciais

$tests[] = [
    "array" => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], 
    "is_sequential" => true,
    "is_associative" => false
];

// Teste 2: Array associativo

$tests[] = [
    "array" => ["name" => "foo", "lastname" => "bar"], 
    "is_sequential" => false,
    "is_associative" => true
];

// Teste 3: Array com chave do tipo string contendo inteiro válido

$tests[] = [
    "array" => ["0" => "foo", "1" => "bar"], 
    "is_sequential" => true,
    "is_associative" => false
];

// Teste 4: Array com índices do tipo float

$tests[] = [
    "array" => [0.5 => "foo", -3.5 => "bar"], 
    "is_sequential" => true,
    "is_associative" => false
];

// Teste 5: Array com índices do tipo booleanos

$tests[] = [
    "array" => [true => "foo", false => "bar"], 
    "is_sequential" => true,
    "is_associative" => false
];

// Teste 6: Array com índice nulo

$tests[] = [
    "array" => [null => "foo"], 
    "is_sequential" => false,
    "is_associative" => true
];

// Teste 7: Array misto

$tests[] = [
    "array" => ["foo", "baz" => "bar"], 
    "is_sequential" => false,
    "is_associative" => false
];

// Teste 8: Array de índices numéricos desordenados

$tests[] = [
    "array" => [1 => "foo", 0 => "bar"], 
    "is_sequential" => true,
    "is_associative" => false
];

// Teste 9: Array de índices numéricos ordenados não sequenciais

$tests[] = [
    "array" => [0 => "foo", 1 => "bar", 6 => "baz"], 
    "is_sequential" => true,
    "is_associative" => false
];
```

### Solução

A solução mais simples que eu consigo ver é verificar o tipo das chaves do *array*, então:

```php
/**
 * Função que testa se o array é sequencial.
 * 
 * @param array Array a ser testado
 * @return bool True se $array for sequencial, False caso contrário
 */

function is_sequential (array $array) {
    return array_filter($array, "is_int", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY) == true;
}

/**
 * Função que testa se o array é associativo.
 * 
 * @param array Array a ser testado
 * @return bool True se $array for associativo, False caso contrário
 */

function is_associative (array $array) {
    return array_filter($array, "is_string", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY) == true;
}
```

> As soluções acima utilizam a coerção nativa do PHP em considerar um *array* não vazio como `true` e um *array* vazio como `false`. Portanto, se qualquer chave/valor do *array* passar pelo filtro definido, o *array* resultante será não vazio e a função retornará `true`. Se nenhum par chave/valor passar pelo filtro, o *array* resultante será vazio e o retorno da função será `false`.

### Testes

A verificação dos testes é feita da seguinte forma:

```php
try {
    foreach ($tests as $i => $test) {
        if ($test["is_sequential"] !== is_sequential($test["array"])) {
            throw new Exception(sprintf("is_sequential: Algo errado não está certo! Teste %d falhou.", $i+1));
        }

        if ($test["is_associative"] !== is_associative($test["array"])) {
            throw new Exception(sprintf("is_associative: Algo errado não está certo! Teste %d falhou.", $i+1));
        }
    }

    echo "Parabéns! Sua função passou em todos os testes.", PHP_EOL;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

### Resultado

O resultado para as funções definidas pode ser encontrado no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HTFo/2), ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/AnF1De).

### Inconsistências

A solução apresentada acima funciona de acordo com as especificações do próprio PHP; isto é, se um *array* possuir pelo menos um valor que possa ser acessado via chave numérica, o *array* deve ser considerado *array* de índices numéricos; se o *array* possuir pelo menos um valor que possa ser acessado via chave do tipo *string*, o *array* deve ser considerado *array* associativo. Por isso, na solução apresentada, um *array* misto deve retornar verdadeiro para ambas as funções. A inconsistência (semântica) que esta solução gera se faz presente quando considerado o seguinte trecho de código:

```
if (is_sequential($array)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        echo $array[$i], PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Ou seja, se o *array* for de índices numéricos, percorra todos os elementos e exiba-os na tela. Se o *array* for misto, um dos elementos não estará acessível desta forma e em algum momento o índice `$i` não existirá, resultando no erro `Undefined offset`.

Uma forma de contornar esta inconsistência é adicionar um novo parâmetro às funções denominado `$strict`, do tipo booleano, que quando for verdadeiro, a função `is_sequential` retorne verdadeiro **apenas** quando o *array* for estritamente de índices numéricos e a função `is_associative` retorne verdadeiro apenas quando o *array* for estritamente associativo. Desta forma, a solução passaria a ser:

```
/**
 * Função que testa se o array é sequencial.
 * 
 * @param array Array a ser testado
 * @param bool Define se a verificação deve ser de modo rigoroso
 * @return bool True se $array for sequencial, False caso contrário
 */

function is_sequential (array $array, bool $strict = false) {
    return array_filter($array, "is_int", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY) == ($strict ? $array : true);
}

/**
 * Função que testa se o array é associativo.
 * 
 * @param array Array a ser testado
 * @param bool Define se a verificação deve ser de modo rigoroso
 * @return bool True se $array for associativo, False caso contrário
 */

function is_associative (array $array, bool $strict = false) {
    return array_filter($array, "is_string", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY) == ($strict ? $array : true);
}
```

Desta forma, o exemplo supracitado passaria a ser:

```
// Array puramente de índices numéricos
$array = ["foo", "baz", "bar"];

// Passará pela condição e será exibido
if (is_sequential($array, true)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        echo $array[$i], PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// Array misto
$array = ["foo", "baz" => "bar"];

// Não passará pela condição e não será exibido
if (is_sequential($array, true)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        echo $array[$i], PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Este exemplo pode ser visto no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HTw1/0) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Y3NJ1k).

---

### Outras soluções apresentadas

> **Nota:** As verificações abaixo, das outras soluções apresentadas aqui, são apenas para efeito de comparação quando considerado todas as situações previstas pela documentação, através das coerções supracitadas. É esperado que as mesmas falharão em alguns testes, pois estas não levam em consideração todas as situações citadas. Esta comparação não deve ser vista como uma forma de demérito da minha parte, desmerecendo os respectivos autores. Inclusive acredito fielmente que qualquer tipo de conteúdo aqui é aproveitado de alguma forma.

1. A solução apresentada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/199688/5878), por BrunoRB, falharia nos testes 4, 5, 7, 8 e 9. Ver os testes [aqui](https://ideone.com/XBq1RR).
2. A solução apresentada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/199090/5878), por Guilherme Nascimento, falharia nos testes 4, 5, 7, 8 e 9. Ver os testes [aqui](https://ideone.com/5vNsAA).
3. A solução apresentada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193942/5878), por Wallace Maxters, falharia nos testes 4, 5, 7, 8 e 9. Ver os testes [aqui](https://ideone.com/WCQEJR).
4. A solução apresentada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90584/5878) (adaptada), por Andrei Coelho, falharia nos testes 4, 7 e 9. Ver os testes [aqui](https://ideone.com/VFzNEb).

Comment: Muito bom mesmo. Uma nota: no meu primeiro código só falha no item 7.

Answer (score 7):

Uma coisa legal que pode ser feita pra saber se o `array` é ou não associativo é convertendo ele para JSON e checando se o primeiro item do mesmo equivale ao caractere `[` ao invés de `{`.

Quando um `array` em PHP é sequencial, a função `json_encode` gera um `array` em formato JSON. Já quando ele não é sequencial (mesmo que todos os índices sejam numéricos)¹,  ele gerará um `Object` em formato `JSON`.

Veja:

```
$sequencial = array('bigown', 'bacco', 'gabe');
$nao_sequencial_1 = array(99 => 'bigown', 'bacco', 1 => 'gabe');
$nao_sequencial_2 = array('bigown' => 'moderador', 'bacco' => 'usuario', 'gabe' => 'cm');
```

Quando chamamos `json_encode`, as saídas são respectivamente:

```
["bigown","bacco","gabe"]

{"99":"bigown","100":"bacco","1":"gabe"}

{"bigown":"moderador","bacco":"usuario","gabe":"cm"}
```

Assim, a verificação do array sequencial poderia ser feita assim:

```
function array_is_list(array $array) {
     return strpos(json_encode($array), "[") === 0;
}
```

**Nota ¹**: Mesmo que todos os índices de um `array` sejam numéricos, isso não o torna sequencial, já que os números podem ser inseridos manualmente desordenadamente.

**Nota ²**: Se você definir os valores dos índices do `array` sequencialmente manualmente, a avaliação de `array_is_list` seria positiva.

Por exemplo, todos os casos abaixo retornariam `TRUE`

```
array_is_list([1, 2, 3]);

array_is_list([0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3]);

array_is_list([0 => 1, 2, 3]);
```

### Atualização

O PHP está para lançar a versão 8.1. Nessa versão, será incluída a função `array_is_list`, conforme a [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/is_list) (que foi aprovada, por sinal).

Sobre essa proposta, temos o seguinte comentários sobre a função

> ... Add a new function `array_is_list(array $array): bool` that will return true if the array keys are 0 .. count($array)-1 in that order. For other arrays, it returns false. For non-arrays, it throws a TypeError.

Comment: Testei com exemplos de arrays simples e o `json_encode` foi metade do tempo que array_keys, mas agora efetuei um teste com o um array multidimensional com mais de 5000 itens (sei que é bem raro, só a nivel de teste mesmo) e ele foi 5 vezes mais lento, no entanto em situações normais ainda sim o json_encode pareceu uma boa. +1

Comment: function is_assoc($var) {
 return is_array($var) and (array_values($var) !== $var);
}

Comment: Vide meu comentário na pergunta

Answer (score 4):

Eu sugiro trabalhar somente as chaves, pois isso pode ser mais performático que trabalhar os valores (itens), pois estes podem ser arrays multidimensionais, então se trabalhar apenas as chaves poderá ter uma leve melhoria.

### Usando array_keys

Outra possível solução que encontrei foi sugerida pelo [Jesse Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/how-to-check-if-php-array-is-associative-or-sequential/265144#comment20074850_265144):

```
function is_seq($array) {
    $k = array_keys($array);
    return $k === array_keys($k);
}

function is_assoc($array) {
    return !is_seq($array);
}
```

- O `$k = array_keys($array);` pega as chaves dos array, por exemplo:

  - `['a' => 'foo', 'b' => 'bar']` → `['a', 'b']`
  - `['foo', 'bar']` → `[0, 1]`
  - `['a' => 2, 99 => 'bar']` → `['a', 99]`
- O `array_keys($k)` "gera" um array com itens que tenham a mesma quantidade de itens que o array original, mas em sequencia començando do `0`

  - `['a' => 'foo', 'b' => 'bar']` → `['a', 'b']` → `[0, 1]`
  - `['foo', 'bar']` → `[0, 1]` → `[0, 1]`
  - `['a' => 2, 99 => 'bar']` → `['a', 99]` → `[0, 1]`

Veja que apenas o exemplo 2 (`... => [0, 1] => [0, 1]`) teve os resultados iguais, isto faz considerar como "sequencia".

No entanto se deseja que o array tenha apenas alguns indices, como por exemplo: `[ 0 => 'foo', 9 => 'bar' ]` então pode usar `array_filter` com `is_string`, este funcionou quando usado `$arr = array(1 => 'bigown', 3 => 'bacco', 2 => 'gabe');`, exemplo mantido por questões de testes:

```
//Checa se é sequencial
function is_seq($array) {
    $result = array_filter(array_keys($array), function ($value) {
        return is_int($value) === false;
    });

    return empty($result);
}

//Checa se é associativa
function is_assoc($array) {
    return !is_seq($array);
}
```

Ou pode fazer assim:

```
function is_seq($array) {
    return ctype_digit(implode('', array_keys($array)));
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
$assoc = array('a' => 1, 2, 3, 4);
$list = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$arr = array(1 => 'bigown', 3 => 'bacco', 2 => 'gabe');

var_dump('$assoc is_assoc: ', is_assoc($assoc));
var_dump('$assoc is_seq: ', is_seq($assoc));

var_dump('$list is_assoc: ', is_assoc($list));
var_dump('$list is_seq: ', is_seq($list));

var_dump('$list is_assoc: ', is_assoc($arr));
var_dump('$list is_seq: ', is_seq($arr));
```

ideone: https://ideone.com/WSOKiB

---

### Testes de performance:

- wallace: 0.0075829029083252ms
- anderson: 0.037861824035645ms
- guilherme1: 0.026437997817993ms
- guilherme2: 0.056728839874268ms

O exemplo do Wallace se saiu melhor e praticamente todos testes, um exemplo:

```
<?php
$array = range(1, 800);

function guilherme1($array) {
    return ctype_digit(implode('', array_keys($array)));
}

function guilherme2($array) {
    $result = array_filter(array_keys($array), function ($value) {
        return is_int($value) === false;
    });

    return empty($result);
}

function wallace($array) {
     return strpos(json_encode($array), '[') === 0;
}

function anderson($array) {
    return array_filter($array, 'is_int', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY) == true;
}

function test($callback, $arr) {
    $x = microtime(true);

    for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $callback($arr);
    }

    echo $callback, ': ', microtime(true) - $x, 'ms', PHP_EOL;
}

test('wallace', $array);
test('anderson', $array);
test('guilherme1', $array);
test('guilherme2', $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Com o array_key_exists você consegue fazer isso, veja:

```
    // array associativo
$arrayAss = array('maçã', 'numero' => 1,  'cor' => 'vermelho');

// array sequencial
$arraySeq = array('maçã', 1, 'vermelho');

// conta quantidades
$quantAss = count($arrayAss);
$quantSeq = count($arraySeq);

$tipo = "sequencial";

// aqui ele vai retornar associativo, pois o for vai passar de forma sequencial e uma hora vai dar "false" no array_key_exists...

for($x = 0; $x < $quantAss; $x ++){

    if(array_key_exists($x, $arrayAss) == false){

        $tipo = "associativo";

        break;

    }

}

echo $tipo;
```

no caso abaixo ele retornará sequencial pois o valor do array_key_exists nunca será false

```
   $tipo = "sequencial";

   for($x = 0; $x < $quantSeq; $x ++){

    if(array_key_exists($x, $arraySeq ) == false){

        $tipo = "associativo";

        break;

    }

}

echo $tipo;
```

fiz o teste aqui e deu certo...

claro que você poderá incrementar a melhor forma para você.

Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução bem concisa usando as fuções [`range`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php) e [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php):

```
// true caso $arrayVar seja uma lista sequencial (indexada de 0 até N, sem gaps)
array_keys($arrayVar) === range(0, count($arrayVar) - 1);
```

Usando os exemplos da questão:

- `array('item 1', 'dois' => 'item 2');` gera `[0, 'dois'] === [0, 1]; // false`
- `array('item 1', 'item 2');` gera `[0, 1] === [0, 1]; // true`

Array vazio daria false já que `range(0, -1)` gera `[0, -1]`, se esse resultado é certo ou errado eu diria que é uma questao filosófica sem resposta ;) mas caso deseje true basta adicionar `$arrayVar &&` antes da comparação.

Comment: O range e o array_keys do primeiro array_keys (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/199090/3635) tem o mesmo efeito, a diferença é que gerar o range é brevemente mais lento.

Comment: Esta forma também não funciona caso os índices não forem sequenciais ou um dos elementos for excluído do array: https://repl.it/HTFo/1

Comment: Para indices não sequencias acredito que esteja correto o comportamento já que a própria questão fala "com números sequenciais". Para exclusão (unset) dependendo de como você quiser ver está certo ou errado.

Comment: Pode ser que sim, mas eu acredito que o "com números sequenciais" ele quis dizer array de índices numéricos, não necessariamente sequenciais. De qualquer forma, acredito mais ainda que seja interessante uma forma que funcione para qualquer situação.

Comment: Sequencial é sequencial. Todas as respostas foram úteis. O que quis dizer é que queria uma solução pra saber se o array do PHP é uma espécie de Hash ou um List (parecido com array do Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

### Array associativo ou numérico

Use a função **array_filter** com a função 'is_string' de *callback*. Em seguida faça uma contagem.

A função array_filter retornará um array somente com as keys associativas, caso existam.

**Exemplo**

```
$array = array('item 1', 'dois' => 'item 2');

$arrayAssociativo = array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_string');

echo count($arrayAssociativo) > 0 ? 'Associativo' : 'Numérico';
```

Comment: Entre count e empty não vejo muitas diferenças: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/199090/3635, basicamente é a mesma resposta.

Comment: O teste ainda pode falhar. Se eu determinar que o `array` seja `[1 => 1, 5 => 5, 10 => 10]`, seu teste vai retornar verdadeiro. É diferente o índice ser sequencial do que ser numérico.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, presumi que com "sequencial" você quis dizer não-associativos. Nesse caso o correto seria retorna "numérico". Editado.

Comment: @IgorAlbuquerque eu achei que sequencial tava fácil de entender que era um array com índices em sequência... tipo 0, 1, 2, 3.. igual no Javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Sempre utilizei a função abaixo para essa verificação:

```
function is_assoc($array)
{

    $arr_keys  = array_keys($array);
    $arr_shift = array_shift($arr_keys);
    if(is_array($array) && !is_numeric($arr_shift))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Explicação do código:

`array_keys` — Essa função está presente no php desde o PHP 4. Retorna todas as **chaves** ou uma parte das chaves de um array.

`array_shift` - retira o primeiro elemento do array e o retorna. Também reordena os índices dos elementos, começando os índices de zero, enquanto as chaves string permanecem alteradas. Foi utilizado aqui apenas para pegar o primeiro elemento do array retornado por array_keys.

Em seguida no `if` verifica se a variável passada é um array e se o elemento da array_key não era um número.

Em suma, se for um array e o índice não for numérico, é um array associativo.

Resposta melhorada após o comentário do Guilherme Nascimento:

```
function is_assoc($array)
{
    if(is_array($array))
    {
        $arr_keys  = array_keys($array);
        $arr_shift = array_shift($arr_keys);

        return !is_numeric($arr_shift); 
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sugestão, reduza disto `if(is_array($array) && !is_numeric($arr_shift))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;` para isto `return is_array($array) && !is_numeric($arr_shift);`

Comment: Na verdade olhando bem a verificação is_array esta em uma ordem bem errada :/, vc checa o is_array depois de usar o array_keys e array_shift.

Comment: Verdade Guilherme, vou melhorar isso.