# O que é na verdade o array?

Tags: array, terminologia, estrutura-de-dados

Meu objetivo aqui é chegar a um conceito mais concreto a respeito do *array*.

Em linguagens como JavaScript o *array* é um objeto que aceita você adicionar e remover membros a uma espécie de lista. Essa lista sempre tem os índices numerados iniciando de 0.

No Python temos algo similar ao *array* do JavaScript, que seria​ o *list* e o *tuple*, salvo esse último que é uma lista imutável mas semelhante.

Porém, no PHP, o *array* parece ser uma mistura de *hash* (ou como o `Object` no JavaScript) com uma lista.

Como minha primeira linguagem de programação foi o PHP, eu acostumei com o `Array` sendo o que é no PHP, mas ao comparar com o *array* do Java, JavaScript e ainda outras linguagens, vejo que mesmo tendo​ a mesma nomenclatura, parecem ser coisas diferentes, gerando uma confusão de termos técnicos.

- Mas afinal de contas, o que é um *array*? É uma lista indexada sequencialmente? Ou é um *container* de itens indexados manualmente (como no PHP)?
- Seria correto afirmar que o conceito de array da linguagem PHP **está errado**? Se está "errado", qual seria o nome mais apropriado para o "array" dessa linguagem?
- Lista e *array* são a mesma coisa? Se não, qual é a diferença?

**Perguntas relacionadas:**

- [Existe alguma maneira de saber se um array é associativo ou sequencial?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90518/5878) (PHP)

Comment: Nome do moderador do stackoverflow pt. :D

Comment: Seria correto afirmar que o conceito de Array da linguagem PHP está errado? R: de certa forma sim, tem outras mil coisas que tem nome inadequado em PHP. Se analisar bem, vai ver que PHP "empresta" muitos nomes de recursos de outras linguagens, mas sem o devido domínio do conceito. Ex: sistema de "tipos" do 7, simulação do comportamento de OO, imitação de "define", etc

Comment: No caso do PHP, mesmo o que seria um simples array, é um associativo: http://ideone.com/iEDhkz (e é por isso que na pergunta sobre como detectar a diferença, faltou o mais importante na maioria das respostas: não tem diferença, pq pro PHP é sempre associativo. Qualquer detecção que não leia o código fonte procurando a definição, não vai diferenciar pq a unica diferença está no fonte, aparentemente).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Mas afinal de contas, o que é um *array*? É uma lista indexada sequencialmente? Ou é um *container* de itens indexados manualmente (como no PHP)?

Formalmente qualquer coisa que não seja uma sequência única e contínua de valores não é um *array*.

Continue usando o termo que todo mundo da comunidade da tecnologia usa.

Cada tecnologia pode dar o nome que quiser para cada elemento dela. Isso não quer dizer que formalmente seja correto na computação, ou mesmo na matemática já que a computação é uma aplicação específica da matemática.

> Seria correto afirmar que o conceito de *array* da linguagem PHP está errado? Se está "errado", qual seria o nome mais apropriado para o "array" dessa linguagem?

É difícil afirmar isso concretamente.

PHP possui uma estrutura com elementos esparsos e seu acesso feito por uma chave que não é a posição do elemento na sequência. Pelo menos ele chama de [***array* associativo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/429851/101) e provavelmente *array* é só uma forma encurtada. Se prestar atenção na documentação é dito que é um *array* associativo apesar de usar o termo `Array` na sintaxe.

Grosso modo ele é o mesmo que uma tabela *hash*. Não precisa chamar de *hash table*, inclusive porque isso pode ser só detalhe de implementação. Algumas pessoas chamam isso de mapa ou dicionário.

Está longe do ideal em performance, mas como é para executar *scripts* nada muito problemático. Tanto *array* quanto *hash table* possuem complexidade O(1), mas o *array* faz uma aritmética simples de ponteiro, uma tabela *hash* precisa de uma aritmética mais complexa e em alguns casos a complexidade da fórmula pode ser O(n) em relação ao tamanho do objeto que serve de chave.

Da mesma forma que se fala em *hash* quando na verdade está se falando *hash table*. Ou quando usa lista para lista ligada. Então dependendo de onde olhar algo pode parecer errado, tem lugar que classificam aquilo da maneira certa, sem simplificação.

> Lista e *array* é a mesma coisa? Se não, qual é a diferença?

Lista é um conjunto de valores que possuem uma certa sequência, mas a forma exata de organização na memória e acesso a ela não é definido. Uma lista deve aceitar novos elementos. Um *array* não costuma aceitar.

Embora o nome *array* possa ser usado existem nomes mais específicos para estruturas de dados mais específicas, exceto para o vetor mais puro. Lista pode ser usado assim livremente, mas dependendo de como ela é implementada ela pode ter um nome mais específico.

Veja [Qual é a função do vetor (array)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124849/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Basicamente, o principal problema no PHP foi centralizar tudo em uma estrutura apenas. Como a própria documentação diz: "*ele pode ser tratado como um array, uma lista (vetor), hashtable (que é uma implementação de mapa), dicionário, coleção, pilha, fila e provavelmente mais*".

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss inclusive lembrando que é sempre associativo no final das contas, mesmo que declarado como array: http://ideone.com/iEDhkz

Comment: Todo e qualquer objeto em memória em Javascript é uma tabela hash. Por isso que arrays em Javascript são tabelas hash.

Answer (score 10):

*"Array"* é uma palavra que já existia muito antes da programação. Este é seu significado, de acordo com o [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/array):

> **verb (used with object)**
>   1.
>   to place in proper or desired order; marshal:
>   (...)
>   **noun**
>   3.
>   order or arrangement, as of troops drawn up for battle.
>   (...)
>   5.
>   a large and impressive grouping or organization of things:
>   He couldn't dismiss the array of facts.
>   6.
>   regular order or arrangement; series:
>   an array of figures.
>   7.
>   a large group, number, or quantity of people or things:
>   an impressive array of scholars; an imposing array of books.
>   (...)
>   9.
>   an arrangement of interrelated objects or items of equipment for accomplishing a particular task:
>   thousands of solar cells in one vast array.

Todos esses significados podem ser resumidos, em português, como ["uma ordenação ou posicionamento de coisas"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/array). Ou um conjunto de coisas.

Quando as primeiras linguagens de programação foram criadas, era necessário criar uma estrutura de dados que pudesse armazenar uma quantidade variável de informações. O nome dado a esse tipo de estrutura foi *"Array"*. O único requisito que ele deveria atender era o de armazenar vários itens de forma ordenada. Com o tempo, foram surgindo novas necessidades, e para cada necessidade surgiu uma nova estrutura de dados: pilha, fila, árvore etc.

Aqui acontece uma coisa interessante. As demais estruturas ou não são "embutidas" na maioria das linguagens/plataformas, ou existem bibliotecas com implementações para elas. Mas o *array* é algo tão simples que faz parte da implementação padrão da maioria das linguagens mais comuns (inclusive é utilizado internamente para implementar várias outras estruturas como a pilha).

Sabemos que arrays são algo conceitual, simples e que quase toda linguagem tem. A forma como cada linguagem implementa esse conceito, no entanto, varia.

Em Javascript, por exemplo, o Array se assemelha a uma lista encadeada simples (ênfase em "assemelha"... Cada motor e interpretador de Javascript implementa de uma forma diferente). Já em C e C++, um *array* é um ponteiro. Isso mesmo, um ponteiro! O *array* nessas linguagens é uma "açúcar sintático" para facilitar navegação pela memória.

Para caracterizar o *array* em nível de implementação, teríamos que caracterizar cada linguagem - e existem muitas delas. Mais útil é entender o array pelo seu conceito. Para simplificar, pense nele apenas como uma estrutura onde você guarda dados de forma ordenada. Se você pode adicionar itens além do tamanho declarado inicialmente, se pode misturar tipos diferentes e outros comportamentos vão variar de acordo com a linguagem que você for utilizar - então é melhor escolher algumas linguagens que você mais gosta, entender como o *array* se comporta nelas, e aprender as técnicas mais comuns de uso. Bom estudo!

Comment: Uma coisa que me parece incorreta, é que um array não necessariamente guarda elementos de forma ordenada. Os índices são de fato ordenados, mas os elementos não.

Comment: @Wilker veja isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101

Comment: @bigown ops. Pego pelo senso comum, quando vem à mente a palavra ordenado vem também a definição de sorted.

Comment: @Wilker normal, todo mundo pensa a mesma coisa, eu pensei por muitos anos. De fato quando se fala ordenado todo mundo pensa no classificado. Não sei qual foi a intenção do Renan, mas por querer ou sem querer ele escreveu certo.

Comment: Eu acho que as pessoas tendem a achar que ordenação é o mesmo que classificação devido à "ordem" alfabética, que é a primeira classificação que todo mundo aprende. Mas o meu conceito é exatamento o da pergunta mencionada.

Answer (score 10):

Array é uma estrutura de dados primitiva sobre as quais estas que vc citou (`Listas`, `Tuplas`) e outros `Objetos` que armazenam dados podem ser construídos.

**Independente de linguaguem**, *array*, nada mais é que um **espaço contínuo na memória reservado para guardar dados**. Deste modo podem ser acessados rápida e diretamente apenas utilizando o índice da posição desejada.

Ao contrário de outras estruturas complexas, como as listas, que necessitam obrigatoriamente que sejam acessados os elementos anteriores ou posteriores (dependendo do tipo de lista).

---

Abaixo pode ser visto a representação desta estrutura na memória bem como os acessos aos elementos do ponto de vista do programador e do sistema operacional.

Note que o valor do índice, na maioria das linguagens inicia-se a partir do **0**.
[image: 1d Array]

Comment: Concordo, por isso citei comumente, queria dar o sentido de senso comum. Acho melhor editar para deixar claro.

Answer (score 6):

Interessante o assunto.
Primeiro, vamos pensar no `array` na sua essência.
Sabemos que uma variável é um nome, uma etiqueta que aponta para um local da memória que armazena um valor.
Estudando a linguagem `C`, da qual derivam a maioria das linguagens mais utilizadas hoje, seja pela sintaxe, seja por ter sida nela baseada, vamos ver que um `array` trata-se de um ponteiro que aponta para uma região contínua de memória, com tamanho fixo, onde armazenamos vários dados/objetos de um mesmo tipo, e para facilitar sua identificação, usamos um mesmo nome de variável.
A definição que o @Wilker colocou explica bem isso:

> espaço contínuo na memória reservado para guardar dados

Pois bem, se tomarmos isso como um conceito inicial, uma variável que aponta para um grupo de objetos do mesmo tipo pode ser entendido com um `array`.

Aqui tem uma característica muito importante: armazenamento contínuo e fixo. Você declara um array, por exemplo assim:  `int[2] x`, o que seria um array de dois valores do tipo `int`, identificado pelo nome de "x".
Aqui já podemos diferenciar uma lista, que é dinâmica, ou seja, permite adicionar/remover objetos, o que caracteriza um objeto que não é fixo, e não pode ser mantido numa região contínua de memória, obviamente por conta de ser dinâmico.

Então podemos dizer, de uma maneira bem resumida, que um `list` seria um `array` dinâmico. Portanto, na minha humilde opinião, baseado nesses conceitos que cite, poderia dizer que:

- **array**: objeto que aponta para uma sequência de objetos, do mesmo tipo, com tamanho fixo, armazenados de maneira contínua;
- **lista**: objeto que armazena uma sequência dinâmica de objetos, do mesmo tipo, armazenados de maneira não contínua.

Também sabemos que em muitas linguagens (como `Java` e `C#`) objetos de lista tem uma série de operações que facilitam o trabalho, como pesquisar e ordenar, que no caso de um `array` teriam de ser implementados manualmente, isso também evidencia a diferença entre os dois.

Answer (score 0):

> Mas afinal de contas, o que é um Array? É uma lista indexada sequencialmente? Ou é um container de itens indexados manualmente (como no PHP)?

Array tem sua origem na álgebra como matriz:

**Matriz :**
"Arranjo de m.n elementos matemáticos dispostos num quadro retangular ou quadrado que comporta m linhas e n colunas."

[Lista dos tipos de matrizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices)

> Seria correto afirmar que o conceito de Array da linguagem PHP está errado? Se está "errado", qual seria o nome mais apropriado para o "Array" dessa linguagem?

Eu creio que o  array em **PHP** se enquadra na definição de `matriz`.

> Lista e Array é a mesma coisa? Se não, qual é a diferença?

`Lista` sem um índice é apenas uma lista um `Array List` é uma matriz.

Comment: Criticas construtivas são bem vindas (mesmo através do negativo), poderia explanar o motivo do negativo para eu melhorar minha resposta e talvez revertê-lo?

Comment: Fácil apertar a setinha para baixo difícil é mostrar onde está o erro.

Comment: Vou opinar, veja nas outras respostas que o array do PHP é associativo, o índice dele não é necessariamente numerado, em geral é uma chave, como uma tabela hash. E Array List não seria uma matriz, pelo menos no Java seria uma lista (estrutura de dados elástica, que pode mudar de tamanho) baseada em um vetor (array, estrutura fixa). É nisso que o pessoal deve ter encrencado com a resposta.

Comment: @piovezan sabe qual a tradução do nome array?

Comment: [Arranjo](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arranjo_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)). Arranjos são indexados por ordinais. Matriz é um arranjo bidimensional. O array do PHP não se enquadra em ser indexado por ordinais (embora possa ser).

Comment: @Piovezan bem, na verdade eu não estou compreendendo o que realmente quer dizer. Na minha resposta eu afirmo que o array do php faz parte de um conceito base chamado matriz, e existem vários tipos de matrizes. Todos esses conceitos tuplas, vetores, array são derivados de matriz. A matriz não necessariamente é bidimensional, o tipo mais simples de matriz é unidirecional. Independente da linguagem o conceito base é matriz, pelo simples fato de que a memória é uma matriz. Veja eu não tenho a mínima intenção de fazer com que o que eu digo seja compreendido como uma verdade absoluta...

Comment: ...essa é a minha interpretação da minha pesquisa.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure

Comment: Bom eu não quero entrar no mérito da questão, eu também tirei que matriz é bidimensional da Wikipédia em português e não sei se lá está correto. Eu só levantei os pontos que achei discrepantes da sua resposta numa lida por cima porque você pediu feedback (naturalmente não fui eu que negativei) e não quero me aprofundar.

Comment: @Piovezan fica tranquilo, eu nem ligo para negativos, eu ligo se negativar e não falar nada.

O fato que as pessoas esperam uma complexidade para algo que é simples. E minha resposta é simples... No final da conta em computação no meu entendimento não há uma estrutura de dados que não seja baseada em uma matriz, mais além acredito que tudo no universo parte de uma matriz `x°`... A complexidade está na manipulação e acesso a matriz... Mas se você é programador deveria se aprofundar, eu ainda vou me dedicar mais a esse tema.