# Qual o motivo de um vetor sem tamanho definido não funcionar?

Tags: array, c++, memória, declaração-de-variável

Eis que se você criar um vetor:

#### Assim `int Vetor[0];` funciona

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int vetor [1];
    vetor[0] = 12;

    cout << vetor[0] << endl;
}
```

#### Assim `int Vetor[];` não funciona e da erro

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int vetor[];
    vetor[0] = 12;

    cout << vetor[0] << endl;
}
```

> error: storage size of ‘vetor’ isn’t known|

Só queria entender isso mesmo. Qual a importância de ter um numero dentro do []?

Comment: C++ . pq quando deixo sem definir ele não funciona.

Comment: Coloque o código e o erro.

Comment: error: storage size of ‘vetor’ isn’t known|

Comment: pronto editado... a unica duvida é so entender isso

Comment: Se você traduzir o erro, talvez entenda melhor o erro.... "o tamanho de armazenamento do 'vetor' não é conhecido"

Comment: O problema ja foi resolvido. Eu entendi pela explicação dada por  bigown♦. Era somente saber a importancia de ter um indice que defina o tamanho do vetor. Valeu ae!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando declaramos uma variável estamos reservando um espaço da memória para ela, nada mais que isto. E a linha `int vetor [];` é só a declaração, nada mais.

Por óbvio a sintaxe da declaração de um [*array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199751/101) exige que se saiba o tipo de dados que ele conterá, e isto tem, sabemos que é um `int` e que provavelmente ele é de tamanho de 4 bytes (é um pouco mais complicado que isto, mas não vem ao caso aqui), e precisamos saber quantos elementos terá no *array* para multiplicar por 4 e saber quantos bytes precisam ser alocados. Onde está essa informação absolutamente necessária? Não tem e não há nada o que fazer para resolver isto.

No exemplo que funciona tem o tamanho 1, que multiplicado por 4 indica que a variável terá 4 bytes reservado na memória. Tudo você precisa saber o tamanho que irá alocar.

[É possível até definir o tamanho na hora de alocar através de uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101), mas não pode ficar sem nada.

É possível que o compilador até descubra o tamanho sozinho dependendo da sintaxe:

```
int vetor[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/Initialization.cpp).

Assim `vetor` terá tamanho 3, e reservará 12 bytes na memória para esta variável, e automaticamente colocará os valores constantes acima.

Comment: Entendido. Muito obrigado !! ;D