# Quais as aplicações de arrays no dia a dia? (exemplos da sua usabilidade)

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Fiz uma pesquisa na internet sobre o uso de arrays e encontrei muitos resultados voltados para a criação de jogos apenas... Mas fora esse exemplo, onde mais uso os arrays (matrizes) no cotidiano (desenvolvimento de aplicações por exemplo)?

Tenho essa dúvida pois a apostila usada em minha disciplina de java na faculdade aborda de maneira resumida os arrays e questionando meu professor sobre o motivo ele me disse que não é muito usual essa estrutura no dia a dia ("não é o foco do java" e você verá o porquê quando estudarmos banco de dados")...

Mas a curiosidade ainda ficou.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays são usados amplamente na linguagem Java. Inclusive `String`s são implementadas por meios de arrays. Existem diversos métodos na JDK em diversas classes que criam ou consomem arrays de diversos tipos.

Entretanto, é verdade que trabalhar-se diretamente com arrays tem lá seus inconvenientes. Frequentemente é uma boa ideia utilizar-se de abstrações mais flexíveis como `ArrayList` (que utiliza um array internamente).

Comment: Assim que você e o @Maniero afirmaram que `arraylist faz uso de array internamente` eu fiquei surpreso e fui ver o codigo fonte. Nunca me passou pela cabeça de que o arraylist usava um array finito, limitado e comum para guardar elementos, mesmo sendo uma classe tão robusta e flexivel.

Comment: @Articuno Quando ele estoura o tamanho, ele cria um novo array maior, copia os elementos e descarta o array antigo.

Comment: O nome da classe indica isso: sou uma lista, mas por baixo tem um array

Answer (score 6):

Bom, na verdade praticamente não há aplicação além de trivial demonstração que não use *array* extensivamente. Então todas as aplicações fazem uso de *array*.

Ainda que em alguns casos o *array* não seja usado diretamente, mas sim dentro de uma estrutura com função semelhante com compromissos um pouco diferentes. Pode ser que o professor estivesse falando disto. A própria *string* é um *array* caracteres. O [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) é outro tipo muito usado e frequentemente preferido em relação ao *array* puro, mas lá dentro tem um *array*, e este tipo não deixa de ser um *array*, só que permite a conveniência de aumentar seu tamanho quando precisa.

Boa parte dos métodos do Java retornam um *array* como resultado da sua operação. Claro que muitos também recebem um *array*. E estou falando do *array* puro mesmo.

[O que é um *array* já foi respondido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199751/101). Resumindo é uma forma de ter várias variáveis com um nome só, todas dispostas em sequência e sendo acessadas por um índice, então há um nome geral e um índice de qual elemento está se referindo.

Uma das maiores vantagens de um computador é computar rápido grandes volumes de dados. É quase inviável ter grandes volumes de dados que não sejam uma sequência de dados parecidos.

Toda vez que é possível ter alguns dados do mesmo tipo com a mesma característica cabe um *array*.

Então você pode ter uma lista de clientes, de pontos, de valores quaisquer, de temperaturas, de arquivos, de palavras diversas, de janelas, URLs, de soldados, enfim, de qualquer objeto.

Uma tabela de banco de dados é muito parecida com um *array* de 2 dimensões. Você tem colunas que por si só não deixa de ser uma sequência de dados e tem linhas com cada entrada na tabela. Mas é mais comum ter um objeto que simule as colunas e o *array* seria equivalente às linhas.

A partir do *array* é possível criar diversas estruturas de dados sequências.

Em geral usa-se laços para acessar e manipular os elementos dos *arrays*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).