# Qual a função do set em associação de objetos?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, getters-setters

Não entendi exatamente para q serve o *set* na associação de objetos.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Local local = new Local("Rua das rosas"); 
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno(22, "Amarildo"); 
        Aluno[] alunos = {aluno};
        
        Professor professor = new Professor("Matusalem", "Retorica");

        Seminario seminario = new Seminario("Velhos e novos deuses", alunos, local);
        Seminario[] seminarios ={seminario};

        professor.setSeminario(seminarios); // Meu problema é especificamente a necessidade desse set

    }

}
```

Vi o uso dele em muitos códigos com relacionamento de objetos, a aplicação ficou meio vazia p mim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em específico parece que nada. Os tais métodos *set* e associar um objeto com outro não tem uma relação direta, mas em algumas situações a associação é feita, e é comum ser com um método deste tipo.

Não vou falar sobre esse método que costuma fazer par com método *get* porque tem uma quantidade imensa de respostas sobre o assunto para estudar com detalhes. Inclusive há quem fale que é comum as pessoas abusarem deles. Tem uma [resposta com *links*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

Tome cuidado com exemplos, especialmente na internet, porque muitas vezes eles demonstram o mecanismo e não como deve fazer códigos reais. Ou até são feitos por alguém que aprendeu programar de forma errada, então se copiar também fará errado, até porque quando está começando você não sabe se a pessoa acertou ou não.

É muito comum que essa associação mostrada na pergunta esteja errada e é uso equivocado desse tipo de método.

Primeiro porque há um [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101) nesse código. E também porque o mais correto seria ter um método que faz a adição de um seminário no objeto de forma mais semântica e não tratar fora. Ou seja, esse *set* sequer deveria existir. Então deveria existir uma [lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250505/101) interna ao objeto que só ele sabe como lidar e expor apenas formas de por ou tirar seminários. O mesmo acontece com os alunos.

Note que, mesmo errado, há uma certa inconsistência. Por que em `Seminarios` há um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) que já aceita os objetos que devem ser associados (e não sei se tem um método *set* para mudar essa associação) e em `Professor` não (parece) tem(r) isso e a forma de associar é um método *set*?

Segundo porque usando um *array* impede mudar sua composição sem criar um objeto novo.

De qualquer forma, usando errado mesmo, você associaria um objeto em outro sem usar um construtor? Tem formas, na verdade que não é bem como associar, e já passei *links* onde pode ver isso.

Outras linguagens podem possuir mecanismo que dispense o método *set* em específico, embora use o mesmo [padrão de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101).

Então entenda todos os mecanismos e como é a real aplicação deles, fugindo dos exemplos ingênuos, simplificados, ou até errados.