# Variável que tem uma variável em seu nome

Tags: javascript, array, declaração-de-variável

Em um exercício:

> Uma empresa deseja saber em quantos meses houve lucro, ou seja, o saldo maior que zero.

O código para resolução foi este:

```
function quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo){
  let quantidade = 0;
  for(let mes = 0; mes < umPeriodo.length; mes++){
    if(umPeriodo[mes] > 0)
    quantidade += 1;
  }

return quantidade;
}
```

A dúvida é em relação à 4ª linha do código em que se expressa:

`if(umPeriodo[mes] > 0)`

Como entender `umPeriodo[mes]`? Não consigo visualizar como funciona, levando em consideração que `umPeriodo = [100, -1, 10, 0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ali recebe um [*array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199751/101). Além de ver o *link* anterior seria bom entender bem [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

Então um *array* sendo variáveis dentro de variáveis, você tem que ter uma forma de dizer qual é o *array* (é o nome da variável principal, no caso `umPeriodo`), e a outra parte que pega a variável interna no *array*, portanto é um índice, normalmente numérico, como em um matriz (em JS é possível que o índice seja diferente, mas parece que nesse caso é numérico e sequencial).

Então você pode acessar `umPeriodo[0]` que é o primeiro elemento do *array* `umPeriodo`. Pode acessar `umPeriodo[1]` que é o segundo elemento, e assim por diante.

No lugar do literal pode usar uma variável, então em cada execução que passa por ali o índice a ser usado será o valor da variável, então vamos pegar o exemplo:

`mes` está valendo 0, portanto `umPeriodo[mes]` na verdade é o elemento `umPeriodo[0]`, e quando `mes` mudar para 1, então teremos `umPeriodo[1]`, e assim por diante.

Você tem um laço ali que faz o valor de `mes` ir mudando em cada passo de execução, em cada uma ele pega o elemento correspondente. É assim que se faz para varrer todo o *array* (tem outras formas como o [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)).

Comment: Obrigado. Super entendi!!!