# Diferença entre dicionários e listas/arrays?

Tags: array, lista, algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados, dicionário

Estou tentando entender o conceito de cada e suas diferenças. Quero entender em quais situações utilizar um ou outro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em geral os 3 são usados para conter elementos (objetos) diversos (pode ser do mesmo tipo ou não, depende da linguagem e forma de uso deles) e o acesso aos elementos são feitos através de um índice. Podemos dizer que ele é um objeto que tem outros objetos dentro dele. Então se uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é um desses objetos você acessa o que quer de verdade através de duas partes:

- a variável que tem o *container*;
- a variável que tem o objeto que realmente quer, e essa parte é acessada pelo índice.

A lista é um pouco mais difícil responder porque depende de como ela é implementada, não existe uma única forma de lista. É comum que uma lista seja só um *array* um pouco mais flexível, mas pode ser uma lista ligada, que muda bastante a forma de acessar cada elemento. Vou pegar a forma mais simples e próxima dos outros.

*Array* e lista já foram respondidos em [O que é na verdade o array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199751/101). Em resumo a lista é o *array* que pode aumentar de tamanho.

O dicionário tem por diferença principal e visível que o índice pode não ser um número e pode não ser sequencial, então até costumamos falar que ele é uma chave em vez de índice. A chave mais comum que é usada é a *string*.

```
variavel["chave"]
```

Algumas linguagem pode ter *syntax sugar* mas ainda é um dicionário com um índice sendo uma *string*:

```
varivavel.chave
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Object.js).

Mas dependendo de como a linguagem implementou isso pode não ser exatamente um dicionário.

Uma das consequências mais óbvias é que os dados não são armazenados na ordem que eles são colocados e sim na ordem da chave, então a estrutura interna é bem diferente. Já vi implementação que na verdade não há ordem alguma (não sei se isso realmente pode ser chamado de dicionário, [tem resposta que ajuda concluir (ou não :D)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/429851/101), há quem prefira usar mapa ou outro termo).

Sem considerar outros tipos de lista, os 3 tem [complexidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/101) de espaço e tempo de acesso aos elementos constante (O(1)) ou pelo menos logarítmico (O(log n)).

Em geral o *array* deve ser usado em primeiro lugar, mas depende da linguagem. Em algumas linguagens a lista é tão simples e eficiente, e mais abstrata que ela é preferida e só se tiver um motivo muito forte deve escolher um *array*. Algumas linguagens quase obriga o uso de *array* em muitos casos (em geral por erro da linguagem/biblioteca). Mas no geral se você não precisa crescer o tamanho do *array* não deveria usar a lista. Reforço que isso não serve para muita coisa sem considerar a filosofia da linguagem.

O dicionário sempre é um pouco pior, então só deve ser usado se for muito importante, e geralmente quando você não pode usar um índice numérico sequencial, precisa de outra forma, precisa da organização das chaves.

Tem linguagem que mistura implementações.