# Ajuda Java: Salvar um ArrayList Key-Value em um BD

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, sqlite

Gostaria de saber como salvar um ArrayList chave e valor no banco de dados usando Java;

Já havia feito uma implementação antigamente em php semelhante,
cujo eu criava o array e usava a função `json_encode($array)` para transformar o array em uma string e `json_decode($array_string)` para converte a string em um array.

Gostaria de saber algum método semelhante que possa usar no Java, lembrando que é um array key-value.

Agredecido.

Comment: Poderia **[edit]** a pergunta com exemplos de dados que estão no `ArrayList`? Digo isso porque em PHP um array [pode ser tanto uma lista sequencial quanto um conjunto de pares de chave/valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90518/112052), mas em Java as estruturas são separadas: `ArrayList` é só uma lista de elementos, e para pares chave/valor usa-se `Map`. De qualquer forma, a melhor forma de gravar no banco vai depender de como estão os dados. Nem sempre transformar em um JSON é a melhor solução, mas sem saber como são os dados, não dá para ajudar muito...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito mais fácil seria implementar essas informações no modelo de entity e salvar utilizando o hibernate, é realmente simples. Já que sua lista seria uma lista da entidade e para salvar bastaria um .save() na entidade, caso hibernate esteja corretamente configurado.
Se você estiver utilizado odbc conector e query pura, não consigo imaginar uma maneira muito pratica que não seja fazer um for e criando uma "stringona" e depois executar o insert.
Uma dica, se for utilizar CHAVE|VALOR em java normalmente utilizamos o MAP<> e não o list.