# Retorno do valor do indice de um array

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho um array com várias posições, como faço para verificar se um determinado indice é numerico ou string?

Comment: [Existe alguma maneira de saber se um array é associativo ou sequencial?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90518/91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No próprio site do php tem essa resposta:
is_numeric:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-numeric.php
is_string:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-string.php

Exemplos:

```php
// valores de uma array
$a = 2;
echo is_numeric($a);
echo is_string($a);
$arr = array(1, "v", 3,"g");
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
        echo "numeric";
    }
    if (is_string($value)) {
       echo "string";
    }
}
// para índices
$produto = [208 => 4, 'Gol' => 84, 'Fox' => 100];
foreach ($produto as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
        echo "numeric";
    }
    if (is_string($key)) {
       echo "string";
    }
}
```

Console:

```
true
false
numeric
string
numeric
string
numeric
string
string
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Isso só foi um exemplo.

Comment: Sim, mas no meu caso não quero verificar o valor, seria o indice, por exemplo: 
$produto = [208 => 4, 'Gol' => 84, 'Fox' => 100];
Seria....
foreach ($produto as $key => $value){
 if(is_numeric($key)){
  echo "Numerico";
 }
}

Comment: Eu sei disso. Mas como vou sabe quais são os índices que vc usou?

Comment: Sim, de mais. Muito Obrigado.