# Qual a diferença entre um mapa, um dicionário, um array associativo e uma tabela hash?

Tags: terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, dicionário, independente-de-linguagem

Estes termos remetem à estruturas que possuem características muito semelhantes, se não iguais. Muitas vezes parecem ser usados intercambiavelmente. Isto seria só nomenclatura diferente dependendo da tecnologia ou tem uma diferença real entre *map* (em geral [*unordered*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101), faz diferença?), *dictionary*, *associative array* e *hash table*?

Um pode ser especialização ou implementação do outro? Quais?

Se eles, ou alguns deles, são iguais e só o nome mudam, sabe se existe alguma razão para ter essa fragmentação de nomenclatura? É possível explicar os nomes serem diferentes?

A Wikipedia parecer indicar que é a mesma coisa (quase todos), mas não sei se não foi um artigo mal escrito, por isso só copiar o que tem lá não terá muito valor. Mas fundamentar com fontes diferentes, mesmo demonstrando incoerência no uso é bem útil e cria conhecimento.

Ver:

- [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)
- [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
- [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html)
- [Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19)
- [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
- [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- [Ruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html)
- [Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html)
- [Harbour](https://harbour.github.io/doc/harbour.html#hb_hash)

Comment: Só responda se entender bem a diferença, uma resposta que "acha" que é, não é boa. Se não surgir nada bom eu responderei depois.

Comment: A nomenclatura "array associativo" foi usada para acessar variáveis em "posições" não numéricas. Por exemplo, em Bash, `${var[1]}` acessa a posição `1` da variável  `var`, enquanto `${var[pos]}` acessa a posição `pos` da variável `var`; e isso é chamado de "array associativo". Por curiosidade, existe um hardware com memória associativa, em que a memória não é acessada por um "endereço numérico", mas por um índice que reflete o conteúdo desejado.

Comment: Engraçado que o tipo "hash" do Harbour `{"nome"=>"Alceu", "idade"=>32}` é o array associativo. Eu preferiria que tivessem chamado de array associativo mesmo... se bem que por ser XBase provavelmente preferiram escolher um nome para o tipo com "inicial desocupada" para [não confundir com outros tipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/70)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como a pergunta é [independente-de-linguagem](/questions/tagged/independente-de-linguagem), vamos focar primeiro em definições que... não dependem de uma linguagem específica, e depois partimos para as especificidades de algumas linguagens que forem pertinentes à discussão.

---

## Definições (independente da linguagem)

### Dicionário x *Map*

Das fontes que consultei, apenas uma dá uma definição que vai na contra-mão do "resto do mundo". É uma diferença sutil, mas acho que vale mencionar.

#### O "do contra"

Segundo o [*Dictionary of Computer Science* da Universidade de Oxford](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199688975.001.0001/acref-9780199688975) <sup>**1**</sup>, o termo "dicionário" [é definido como](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199688975.001.0001/acref-9780199688975-e-1395?rskey=qgbzep&result=1561):

> *Any data structure representing a set of elements that can support the insertion and deletion of elements as well as a test for membership.*

<sup>Obs: a versão *online* só tem esta frase. Para ter a definição completa, só adquirindo a versão paga (ps: eu não adquiri).</sup>

Ou seja, segundo esta definição, um dicionário é um conjunto de elementos no qual você pode adicionar e remover elementos, além de verificar se um elemento está contido nele. Importante notar que não são mencionados chaves e valores, tão comumente associados aos termos da pergunta.

Nesta [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178846) também é dada a definição de *mapping* (que não aparece na versão online do Dicionário de Oxford <sup><sub>*então acredito que o autor da resposta deva ter o livro*</sub></sup>):

> ***mapping** An operation that associates each element of a given set (the domain) with one or more elements of a second set (the range).*

Vale notar que o termo é *map**ping*** (a **operação** de mapear um elemento de um determinado conjunto para um ou mais elementos de outro conjunto). Já o *map* seria uma estrutura que usa esta operação para manter os pares chave-valor(es). Lembrando que as implementações podem ou não exigir que chaves sejam únicas (porém, as definições parecem deixar isso em aberto).

A mesma [resposta já citada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178846) defende - com base nas definições da Oxford - esta distinção entre os termos, e afirma que um dicionário só é um *map* se ele suportar as seguintes operações (que não seriam obrigatórias para todo dicionário):

- guardar elementos com valores distintos de chave/valor
- consultar e apagar valores, **usando-se apenas a chave**

Portanto, segundo a definição da Oxford, dicionário seria uma estrutura mais genérica, que permite adicionar e remover elementos, além de verificar se determinado elemento pertence à estrutura, mas sem necessariamente ter pares de chave-valor.

Já um *map* seria uma estrutura que mapeia um conjunto de chaves para seus respectivos valores, além de permitir as mesmas operações do dicionário (adicionar, remover, consultar), porém usando-se a chave para tal. Seria, portanto, um caso especial de dicionário.

Porém, a própria resposta já citada reconhece que esta distinção não é o "entendimento comum", já que a maioria parece acreditar que dicionário e *map* são sinônimos, e portanto, os termos seriam intercambiáveis (inclusive, outras respostas à mesma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2884068) seguem esta linha).

---

#### O "senso comum"

Também consultei o [*Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures* do NIST](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/) <sup>**2**</sup> (citado [nesta resposta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/30931)) e ali o termo ["dicionário" é definido como](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/dictionary.html):

> *An abstract data type storing items, or values. A value is accessed by an associated key. Basic operations are new, insert, find and delete.*

Importante notar que é dito que "dicionário" é um [ADT (*Abstract Data Type*)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10267084), ou seja, ele só diz o que a estrutura faz (guarda valores que são acessados por suas respectivas chaves, além de poder adicionar, remover e procurar valores), mas não como isso é feito (não dá nenhum detalhe sobre a implementação). E ao contrário da definição de Oxford, ele diz que um dicionário associa (ou mapeia) chaves com seus respectivos valores. Portanto, não há a separação entre *dictionary* e *map*, tanto que a [definição de *map*](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/#M) do NIST é:

> map: see [dictionary](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/dictionary.html)

Consultando outros materiais ([1](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/CS3/html/Dictionary.html), [2](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Ekube/cls/100/Lectures/lec16/lec16-34.html), [3](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse332/12su/slides/lecture04-dictionary.pdf#page=6), [4](http://cs.brown.edu/cgc/java3.datastructures.net/handouts/Dictionaries.pdf), entre muitos outros similares), a impressão que tenho é que a grande maioria parece discordar de Oxford e define que o dicionário obrigatoriamente faz o mapeamento chave-valor, e que os valores sempre são adicionados, atualizados, removidos e buscados a partir da chave.

Muitas fontes ainda adicionam o fato de que a ordem das chaves não é garantida (neste caso seria um *dictionary*/*map* *unordered*) - ou seja, se você iterar pelas chaves, elas podem vir em qualquer ordem, que varia conforme a implementação. Porém, em muitas definições também há a separação dos dicionários em ordenados e não-ordenados, indicando se as chaves devem ou não ser mantidas em determinada ordem, o que também depende da implementação: pode ser a ordem em que foram inseridas (*insertion order*), ordem alfabética ou qualquer outro critério (neste caso seria *sorted* - ["classificado" em vez de "ordenado"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/112052)), etc. Em caso de ter alguma ordem ou classificação definida, ele é chamado de *ordered*/*sorted* *dictionary*/*map* (alguns não fazem a distinção entre *ordered* e *sorted* e acabam escolhendo apenas um dos termos).

Enfim, a ideia de que dicionário e *map* são a mesma coisa está tão difundida que parece ser o "senso comum". Com base nas fontes já citadas (e várias outras que não citei por serem redundantes), me parece que ambos se referem a uma estrutura de dados abstrata (ADT, só diz o que faz, mas não impõe detalhes de implementação), que mapeia chaves a seus valores, e possui operações para adicionar, atualizar, remover e buscar elementos (ou verificar se um elemento existe), usando-se as chaves para tal.

---

**Há ainda outro termo**: o livro [*Algorithms*, de Sedgewick e Wayne](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/), descreve o termo [***Symbol Table*** (Tabela de Símbolos)](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/31elementary/), que pela definição, é basicamente "o mesmo" que dicionário/*map*:

> *The primary purpose of a symbol table is to **associate a value with a key**. The client can insert key–value pairs into the symbol table with the expectation of later being able to search for the value associated with a given key.*

Ou seja, além de ter o mapemaneto chave-valor, o livro também menciona as operações básicas (adicionar, remover, buscar/verificar se existe), além de descrever várias opções que podem ser escolhidas pelas implementações, como o tipo das chaves, se permite chaves duplicadas, valores nulos, se as chaves estão em determinada ordem (*Ordered symbol tables*, que permitiriam operações adicionais, como obter o valor da maior ou menor chave, ou de chaves que estão em determinado intervalo), etc.

Por fim, outras fontes também mencionam os termos "tabela", ou "*associative container*" como sinônimos (embora "tabela" dê a impressão de que está expondo um detalhe de implementação, conforme o próximo item).

---

### Tabela *Hash*

Uma tabela *hash* é uma forma de implementar um dicionário. O NIST, por exemplo, [define *hash table* assim](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/hashtab.html):

> *A dictionary in which keys are mapped to array positions by hash functions.*

Ou seja, é uma das implementações possíveis de um dicionário (já que também pode ser feito com [árvores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), por exemplo). Neste caso, ele usa uma tabela *hash*, que por sua vez usa uma função de *hash* (que calcula um valor a partir da chave, sendo que esse valor é chamado de *hash*, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27827/112052) para mais detalhes).

Claro que a implementação também pode variar, já que há muitas formas de se criar uma função de *hash*, de [tratar colisões](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution), etc.

---

### Array associativo

No [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), os termos "dictionary", "map" e "associative container" redirecionam para "Associative array", o que dá a impressão de que este seria o termo "correto" e que os outros seriam sinônimos.

Porém, já houve discussão sobre o nome do artigo, [sugerindo mudá-lo para `Map` ou `Dictionary`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Associative_array#Naming_discussion_.28assoc_array_vs._dict_vs._hash_etc.29), argumentando que são termos mais usados que "array associativo" (que por sua vez, seria o "menos popular", pois "só PHP usa" <sup><sub>*reclamem com quem iniciou a discussão, não comigo*</sub></sup>). Mas pelo jeito não foi pra frente, já que o nome do artigo continua sendo "Associative array".

No fim das contas, seria o mesmo que dicionário/*map*, apenas mais um termo para se referir à mesma coisa. Porém, pode-se argumentar que "array" na verdade está [expondo um detalhe de implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/112052), e que portanto não seria um ADT, ou que ter "array" no nome é confuso, já que se trata de outra estrutura de dados completamente diferente (esse foi um dos argumentos para defender a mudança no nome do artigo, aliás).

O NIST [define "associative array" desta forma](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/assocarray.html):

> *A collection of items that are randomly accessible by a key, often a string.*

O que me parece similar a um dicionário, embora só haja uma menção explícita à operação de consulta. Mas acredito que as outras estejam implícitas, afinal, se não desse nem para adicionar, seria uma estrutura de utilidade bem limitada.

Fora a Wikipedia, a única fonte que encontrei que menciona este termo (como conceito abstrato e independente de linguagem) é o [já citado livro *Algorithms*](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/31elementary/), ao falar sobre o caso específico em que uma tabela de símbolos não permite chaves duplicadas:

> *`Duplicate keys`. Only one value is associated with each key (no duplicate keys in a table). When a client puts a key-value pair into a table already containing that key (and an associated value), the new value replaces the old one. These conventions define the **associative array abstraction**, where you can think of a symbol table as being just like an array, where keys are indices and values are array entries.*

Ou seja, mesmo que o termo seja mencionado, ele refere-se a um tipo específico de dicionário (e ainda me passa uma impressão de que há vazamento de abstração, ao citar explicitamente uma tabela e sua correlação com o array).

Portanto, não fico seguro em afirmar que, conceitualmente falando, "array associativo" é um termo equivalente a "dicionário" ou "*map*" (exceto se determinada implementação garantir que é, para o seu contexto específico).

---

Dado tudo que foi dito acima, me parece que o "senso comum" é de que os conceitos de dicionário e *map* são aceitos como sinônimos (ADT, mapeia chave-valor, operações básicas), enquanto array associativo é um pouco mais debatível. No fundo, depende de para quem você pergunta, mas os links estão aí e cada um que tire suas próprias conclusões.

Já o termo "tabela *hash*" refere-se à [implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/112052).

---

## Implementações

Não vou colocar todas as linguagens, apenas citarei alguns casos que achei pertinentes. Se quiser um comparativo mais completo, tem [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(associative_array)).

De forma geral, vejo que cada linguagem dá o nome que quer, e nem sempre corresponde às definições acima. E como as próprias definições dos conceitos também divergem em certos pontos, me parece - infelizmente - natural que as implementações também o façam.

> **Lembrando que tudo que é dito abaixo sobre as linguagens referem-se à *implementação atual* (exceto quando versões anteriores forem mencionadas), consultadas na data desta resposta. Pois como são detalhes de implementação, podem perfeitamente mudar - muitas vezes sem aviso - em versões futuras.**

---

### Java

Em Java existe a [classe abstrata `Dictionary`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Dictionary.html) (**obsoleta**) e uma [subclasse `Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html), o que mostra que pelo menos conceitualmente houve uma preocupação com a nomenclatura (já que um dicionário é um ADT e uma das formas de implementar é com tabelas *hash*).

Porém, a recomendação é que qualquer implementação atual use a [interface `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) e suas várias implementações. A mais comum (pelo menos é a que vejo sendo usada com mais frequência) é o `HashMap`, que [segundo a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) (e como o próprio nome diz) é implementando com uma tabela *hash* e não garante a ordem das chaves. Mas também há implementações que garantem a ordem, como [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) (que é implementado com uma [árvore rubro-negra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) e usa a ordem natural das chaves, mas você também pode customizar a ordenação usando um [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html)) ou [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), que mantém as chaves na ordem em que foram inseridas (usando uma tabela *hash* para o dicionário e uma lista duplamente ligada para manter a ordem das chaves).

Ou seja, Java optou pelo termo `Map` (<speculation>talvez porque `Dictionary` já havia sido usado, e depois que esta classe ficou obsoleta, acabaram tendo que usar outro termo</speculation>), cuja implementação está de acordo com as definições vistas acima. Claro que há alguns detalhes específicos (algumas classes permitem chaves e/ou valores nulos, outras não, etc), mas de forma geral, me parece não desviar das definições.

---

### Python

Em Python existe o [dicionário (`dict`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping), que me parece estar de acordo com as definições acima (possui as operações para adicionar/remover/atualizar/procurar chaves, que são mapeadas para os respectivos valores).

Um detalhe é que a partir do Python 3.7 é garantido que as chaves estarão na ordem em que foram inseridas (obs: no CPython 3.6 isso era um detalhe de implementação, mas a partir do Python 3.7 isso é garantido - e [aprovado pelo próprio BDFL](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) - para todas as implementações da linguagem - ver mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744)).

Vale lembrar que também existe o [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), que além de manter as chaves em ordem de inserção, possui outras funcionalidades, como a opção de [mover uma chave para o final](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end), além de levar em conta a ordem nas comparações:

```py
d1 = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
d2 = { 'b': 2, 'a': 1 }
# chaves em ordem diferente
print(d1.keys()) # dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
print(d2.keys()) # dict_keys(['b', 'a'])
# apesar disso, os dicionários são iguais
print(d1 == d2) # True

# com OrderedDict, é diferente
from collections import OrderedDict
d1 = OrderedDict({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 })
d2 = OrderedDict({ 'b': 2, 'a': 1 })
print(d1.keys()) # odict_keys(['a', 'b'])
print(d2.keys()) # odict_keys(['b', 'a'])
# chaves não estão na mesma ordem, dicionários não são iguais
print(d1 == d2) # False
```

Internamente, [um `dict` é implementado com uma tabela *hash*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/327311).

---

### C#

Em C# temos a [classe `Dictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8), que representa uma coleção de chaves e valores, não garante a ordem das chaves e é implementado com uma tabela *hash*. Existe também o [`SortedDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8), que ordena as chaves e é implementado com uma árvore binária.

---

### JavaScript

Historicamente, objetos têm sido usados como dicionários/*maps*, já que eles possuem as funcionalidades necessárias: posso adicionar, apagar e obter valores a partir de uma chave, além de testar a existência da mesma. Ex:

```js
const obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };
// atualiza a chave e obtém o valor
obj.a = 3;
console.log(obj.a); // 3
// se a chave existe, apaga
if ('b' in obj) delete obj['b'];
console.log(obj); // { a: 3 }
```

Vale lembrar que o uso de objetos como dicionários tem alguns poréns: o protótipo do objeto pode ter propriedades (ou seja, "chaves") que podem conflitar com aquelas definidas no próprio objeto:

```js
Object.prototype.c = 3;
const obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };
// verifica se a chave "C" está no objeto
console.log('c' in obj); // true (pois a propriedade "c" está no prototype)
```

Neste caso, a solução para evitar este problema seria usar um [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), que é um objeto específico para guardar pares de chave-valor, além de ter todas as operações de um dicionário e manter as chaves na ordem de inserção (o `Map` não existia nas versões iniciais da linguagem, o que pode explicar a preferência por usar objetos como dicionários, muito comum até hoje). Veja a diferença:

```js
Object.prototype.c = 3;
const obj = new Map([ ['a', 1], ['b', 2] ]);
// verifica se a chave "C" está no objeto
console.log(obj.has('c')); // false (não é afetada pelo prototype)

// se usar o operador "in", ele ainda olha no prototype
// por isso, para ver se a chave existe no Map, o recomendado é usar has()
console.log('c' in obj); // true
```

Há outras diferenças entre um `Map` e um objeto "comum", [veja aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps) para mais detalhes. Mas de forma geral, o `Map` me parece mais adequado, pois a impressão que tenho é que foi feito especialmente para ser uma implementação de um dicionário.

Ver também:

- [Os objetos nativos do JS são arrays associativos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/112052)
- [Objetos são semelhantes a arrays?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122341/112052)
- [Pra que serve o objeto Map em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313916/112052)

---

### PHP

Em PHP existe o array, que na verdade é uma estrutura "faz-tudo". Segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (com ênfase minha):

> *An array in PHP **is actually an ordered map**. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more*

Ou seja, no fundo o array é um dicionário/*map*, mas que pode ser tratado como o array "clássico" de outras linguagens (estrutura sequencial com índices numéricos), tendo os índices numéricos agindo como chaves. Interessante que o trecho acima trata a tabela *hash* (uma implementação de *map*) e o dicionário como dois itens distintos.

Vale lembrar também que a documentação menciona que "*PHP arrays can contain int and string keys at the same time as PHP does not distinguish between indexed and associative arrays*". Repare no uso do termo "associative array". De fato, conforme argumentado na discussão da Wikipedia - e pelo menos nas linguagens que conheço melhor - PHP parece ser uma das poucas linguagens que usam este termo oficialmente, para se referir a uma estrutura que implementa o conceito do ADT dicionário/*map*.

Em JavaScript, por exemplo, encontramos o termo "associative array" [na documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) ("*If you want to use an ordered associative array in a cross-browser environment, use a Map object*"), mas a [especificação da linguagem](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/) não contém nenhuma menção ao termo. Outras linguagens parecem preferir dicionário ou *map*, mas como já disse, não conheço todas, então (sempre) tem uma chance de eu estar enviesado/errado.

Ver também:

- [Como funciona internamente os arrays do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361149/112052)
- [O que é na verdade o array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199751/112052)
- [Existe alguma maneira de saber se um array é associativo ou sequencial?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90518/112052)

---

### Ruby/Perl

Em Ruby existe a [classe `Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html), que mapeia pares de chave-valor e possui as operações já mencionadas (adicionar, remover, etc). Em Perl, a estrutura que possui essas características também se chama [`Hash`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro#Hashes)), embora haja menção a "associative array" na [documentação](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7#What-are-all-these-%24%40%25%26%2A-punctuation-signs%2C-and-how-do-I-know-when-to-use-them%3F).

Enfim, este exemplo foi só para registrar mais um dos muitos nomes usados para se referir à implementação de um dicionário.

---

## Conclusão

Os termos "dicionário", "*map*" e "array associativo" podem ou não ser intercambiáveis, dependendo do contexto. Em alguns círculos/comunidades, uns podem ser mais aceitos que outros, e os nomes escolhidos pela linguagem podem ter forte influência nisso.

A definição mais, digamos, acadêmica considera que dicionário e *map* referem-se ao ADT (podendo ser idênticos, ou um ser uma variação do outro), enquanto "array associativo" parece ser mais restrito e controverso. Características como a ordem/classificação ou a unicididade das chaves podem ou não ser consideradas "obrigatórias". Quanto à implementação, cada linguagem dá o nome que bem entender (algumas são mais "fiéis" às definições, outras nem tanto).

Já a tabela *hash* eu não diria que é intercambiável, por se tratar de um detalhe específico de implementação.

Enfim, o que fica é a dica de ler a documentação de cada linguagem para saber o que de fato é cada estrutura, já que somente pelos nomes não dá para ter 100% de certeza sobre o que eles são. Eu não sei os motivos de cada uma ter optado por determinado nome, e nem quero especular, só posso lamentar por ser tão bagunçado. Isso mostra que de fato [é complicado dar nomes para as coisas](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html).

---

<sup>**1** - neste caso, é tanto um dicionário no sentido não-computacional (um livro que contém a definição de vários termos), como no sentido computacional (mapeia cada termo - que seriam as chaves - para sua respectiva definição - que seriam os valores) :-)

**2** - idem 1 (mas em vez de livro, é um site)</sup>

Comment: Uma das coisas que eu *acho*, já que não tem consenso absoluto, é que o dicionário tem chave única (`dict<word, definitons>`) e o mapa não necessariamente (`map<word, definiton>`, note a sutileza), embora possa ter. A tabela e o *array* são mesmo detalhes de implementação, sendo o *array* associativo um nome errado de chamar a tabela *hash* (PHP sendo PHP e outros indo na onda). Boas linguagens escolhem se querem um ADT ou um detalhe exposto, só para confirmar sua resposta, que acho que passa ser uma das melhores fontes sobre o assunto na internet, ainda que não encerre o assunto.

Comment: Eu acho que algumas definições "formais" citadas são muito sem vergonhas, parece não ser bem pensadas, mas é o que tem, a pesquisa aqui foi boa.

Comment: Eu gostaria que fosse: hashtable => unordered (unique); associative array => ordered (non unique); dictionary => sorted (unique, mas deveria ter um outro nome para a estrutura classificada com duplicidade de chaves); map => implementação e garantias não definidas, só tem chave e valor, e manipulação das entradas como requisitos, e pode ter mais e uma entrada. O mapa eu fico mais em dúvida, quem sabe ele deveria ser o multi sorted e não ter um mais abstrato. Faz sentido?

Comment: @Maniero Num mundo ideal teríamos estruturas com nomes bem definidos e que não variam conforme a linguagem/tecnologia. Poderia ser sua ideia, assim como qualquer outra variação, desde que fosse consenso geral, e não a bagunça que é atualmente. Mas como a chance de alguém arrumar isso e conseguir um consenso comum a todos é bem pequena, só nos resta aceitar que cada linguagem vai usar os termos que bem entender, e a gente que se vire :-/

Answer (score 11):

Array associativo (Javascript, PHP), dicionário (Python) e Map (Java, C++) são a mesma coisa.

Também são chamados de "hash", mas isso é uma metonímia, a função de hash é o coração de uma implementação eficiente de array associativo. Mas pode-se implementar array associativa de outros jeitos.

Em Java, Map é a interface de array associativo. HashMap é uma implementação de Map que usa hash, EnumMap é uma impl. que usa um vetor (array sequencial), LinkedHashMap permite o acesso das chaves na ordem em que foram inseridas, e TreeMap permite o acesso das chaves em ordem alfabética/numérica (implementação é baseada em árvore, não em hash).

Comment: Para quem também ficou boiando sobre o que é metonímia: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meton%C3%ADmia

Answer (score -4):

Um mapa, um dicionário, um array associativo e uma tabela hash são estruturas de dados que permitem associar valores a chaves para realizar operações de busca, inserção e remoção eficientes. Embora esses conceitos tenham semelhanças, existem diferenças sutis entre eles.

Mesmo assim os termos mapa, dicionário, array associativo e tabela hash são frequentemente usados de forma intercambiável, dependendo da linguagem de programação ou contexto. No entanto, eles se referem a estruturas de dados que têm em comum a capacidade de associar chaves a valores, com diferentes implementações e nuances específicas em cada caso. A escolha da estrutura a ser usada depende das necessidades específicas de um projeto e das características da linguagem de programação em questão.