# Qual a diferença entre estruturas de dados e tipos abstratos de dados?

Tags: terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, ciência-da-computação

Procurei em alguns livros e em algumas páginas da internet, mas não consegui uma resposta clara.

Comment: Tipo abstrato descreve o que o tipo faz, é a 'API' por assim dizer. Estrutura de dados é a coisa real, é como o tipo é implementado.

Comment: O que me deixa confuso são estruturas como AST e ASG onde os 'As' nas siglas já significam Abstrato(Abstract Syntax Tree e Abstract Semantic Graph).

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 8):

Diz-se que ADT é a forma abstrata de definir estruturas sem especificar a forma como ela funciona, sem a preocupação com certos critérios, ou seja, se você quer colocar uma lista de objetos seu Abstract Data Type é a Lista.

Começamos falar em estrutura de dados quando especificamos a implementação, por exemplo dessa lista. Então se é uma lista como um *array*, se é usado um *hash*, se é ligada, etc., então ela é a forma concreta de fazer o ADT. A estrutura de dados define os detalhes de como os dados se dispõe, como serão colocados, recuperados, removidos, como podem ser computados, quais as condições que cada operação ocorrerá, como será o consumo de memória, de tempo para cada tipo de algoritmo, etc.

Vou dar um exemplo que eu acho que ajuda entender e tem relação com as perguntas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455479/101 e [Qual a diferença entre um mapa, um dicionário, um array associativo e uma tabela hash?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/429851/101).

Vamos dizer que você tem um mecanismo chamado dicionário, isso é um ADT. Ele pode dar algumas características que ele deve ter para resolver certos problemas. Cada linguagem ou biblioteca pode entregar esse dicionário com essas características do jeito que quiser. Portanto a implementação pode escolher a estrutura de dados que quiser para produzir o resultado esperado dando as oportunidades determinadas pelo ADT. Pode fazer as maiores maluquices que desejar. Pode usar uma estrutura de dados de uma árvore rubro negra. Mas nada impede de usar outras árvores diversas, ou um *Skip List*, ou até uma forma de *hash* de o ADT não falar que precisa de ordem (geralmente precisa), ou poderia usar um *array* se não precisa achar um dado com tempo próximo de constante (o que costuma precisar, só um exemplo).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: eu vi a mesma coisa Maniero, como se fosse Classe/Objeto... são aqueles termos que se confundem, parecem a mesma coisa, e devem ter uma sutil diferença. Lembro que na faculdade estei "estruturas de dados", o termo *"abstract data type"* é mais "chique" :)

Comment: Acho que entendi o que quer dizer, mas classe e objeto não se confundem https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101. Eu entendo que sejam coisas diferentes tb e isso q respondi está correto, mas acho frouxo, quero tentar achar algo mais sólido que isso, pode ser que não exista. Eu vou tentar explicar porque a diferença faz sentido, preciso achar o tom do texto.

Comment: O artigo _The Birth of Simula (Stein Krogdahl)_ fala de uma possível origem dos TADs: object-orientation _"paved the way for the later concept of abstract data types (see C. A. R. Hoare. Proof of correctness of data representations. 1972)"_. Interessante TADs serem (um pouco) posteriores a objetos.