# Ler números repetidos em um array (ou lista). Retornar o número, quantas vezes ele se repete e em quais posicões?

Tags: java, algoritmo

Questão:

> "Faça um algoritmo para ler 50 números (coloquei 5 para testar) e armazenar em um vetor VET, verificar e escrever se existem números repetidos no vetor VET e em que posições se encontram"

Eu gostaria de refazer essa questão sem usar `ArrayList` ou `Map`. Até agora, o que eu consegui fazer foi mostrar os números que se repete e quantas vezes, mas não sei como dizer as posições que ele se repete.

Gostaria que a saída fosse assim, por exemplo:

```
"numero 2 se repete 3 vezes nas posicoes: [0,3,4]"
"numero 4 se repete 2 vezes nas posicoes: [1,2]"
```

No meu código a saída está assim, por exemplo:

```
"Numero 2 se repete 3 vezes"
"Numero 3 se repete 2 vezes"
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    public static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
        for(int i = 0;  i < 5; i++) {
            lista.add(entrada.nextInt());
        }
        Collections.sort(lista); // ordena a lista em ordem alfabética.

        Map<Integer, Integer> cont = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int repeticao : lista) {
            if (!cont.containsKey(repeticao))
            cont.put(repeticao, 0);
            cont.put(repeticao, cont.get(repeticao) + 1);
        }
        
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : cont.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue() > 1)
                System.out.printf("\nNumro %s se repete %d vezes", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Sem usar `Map` teria que simular um com um `Array` de `Arrays` no formato `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2]....[keyN, valueN]]`. Além do problema da implementação essa condição vem acompanhada da incrível perda de desempenho pois Tabelas de Hash(`HashMap`) apresentam complexidade de tempo *O(1)* em operações de busca, Arvores Binárias(`TreeMap`) apresentam complexidade de tempo *O(log n)* em operações de busca, enquanto `Arrays` apresentam complexidade de tempo *O(n)* em operações de busca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem usar `ArrayList` até dá, basta trocar para um *array*. Mas sem `Map` fica desnecessariamente mais complicado, não vejo motivo para fazer de outra forma.

---

## Com `Map` (mantendo o `ArrayList`)

Em vez de `Map<Integer, Integer>`, use um `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`, que para cada número, guarda uma lista das posições em que o número aparece. Depois, na hora de imprimir, basta mostrar apenas os que aparecem em mais de uma posição.

```java
List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    numeros.add(entrada.nextInt());
}

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> cont = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.size(); i++) {
    int n = numeros.get(i);
    if (!cont.containsKey(n)) {
        cont.put(n, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    // adiciona "i" na lista de posições em que o número aparece
    cont.get(n).add(i);
}

for (Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : cont.entrySet()) {
    List<Integer> posicoes = entry.getValue();
    if (posicoes.size() > 1) {
        System.out.printf("Número %d se repete %d vezes nas posições: %s\n", entry.getKey(), posicoes.size(), posicoes);
    }
}
```

Troquei o `TreeMap` (que guardaria os números em ordem crescente) para `LinkedHashMap`, que guarda os números na ordem em que foram inseridos (o que parece estar mais de acordo com o que precisa: por exemplo, se digitar "1 2 3 2 1", no final mostrará primeiro 1 e depois o 2). Mas se a ordem deles tanto faz (pois o que interessa é apenas se eles se repetem), poderia trocar para `HashMap` sem problemas.

---

## Com `Map` e array

Já se fosse com array, seria assim:

```java
int[] numeros = new int[50];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    numeros[i] = entrada.nextInt();
}

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> cont = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    int n = numeros[i];
    if (!cont.containsKey(n)) {
        cont.put(n, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    cont.get(n).add(i);
}

// restante é igual
```

---

Na verdade daria para computar tudo no mesmo *loop* que lê os dados:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> cont = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    int n = entrada.nextInt();
    if (!cont.containsKey(n)) {
        cont.put(n, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    cont.get(n).add(i);
    numeros[i] = n;
}
```

E *na verdade*, nem precisaria do array para guardar os números, afinal, se você só quer saber os números que foram digitados mais de uma vez (e a "posição" seria relativa à ordem em que eles foram digitados), ter apenas o `Map` já seria suficiente.

---

## Sem `Map`

Se não quer usar `Map`, você teria que implementar manualmente o mapeamento entre cada elemento e suas respectivas posições.

Esta é a pior opção, pois consiste em basicamente reiventar a roda (e possivelmente de um jeito pior).

Claro, você até poderia fazer um loop pelos números, e para cada um, contar quantas vezes cada um ocorre e imprimir as posições, mas é algo tão pior e mais ineficiente que não vale a pena se desfazer do `Map`.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu conseguir resolver de um jeito muito mais simples, mas provavelmente menos eficiente. O problema é que eu ainda não entendo bem essas estruturas de dados como map, LinkedHash, TreeMap, etc...eu ainda não estou nesse nível, por isso queria uma solução que eu pudesse entender. O que eu fiz foi pegar o array normal, mais um array sem as repeticoes do primeiro e mais uma lista para guardar as posicoes que se repetem e a quantidade de vezes, que é o tamanho do array list. Depois de cada loop eu dei um clear() na lista. Mas obrigado pela resposta, vou estudar seu codigo pra upar.

Comment: O ruim é que não fica salvo essas informações, minha intençao era somente imprimir na tela as informações, mas se perdem a cada loop. Sua solução realmente é a melhor, eu tenho que estudar map urgentemente.

Comment: @pauloestevão, veja se o ajuda nos estudos https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/515971/137387